# Sorting list into sections for tableview index

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, dictionary, swift

I'm looking for the best way to take in a list and sort it into sections to be used for a tableView index along the side.  In my example, sorting Car objects by first letter of Make. I was thinking I wanted a dictionary of Car objects with up to 26 keys but don't yet have it working.  If there is a better way that I'm overlooking, I'd love to hear it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Pasting in playground sample.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

let indexList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

func gimmeOne(things: [String]) -> String {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random()) % things.count
    let choice = things[randomNumber]
    return choice
}

func gimmeCarMake() -> String {
    let makes = ["Ford","Audi","Hennessey","Acura","Infiniti","BMW","Lexus","Jeep","Subaru","Nissan","Aston Martin","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Toyota","Volkswagen","Scion","Mitsubishi","Mini","Lotus","Lamborghini","Jaguar","Hyundai","Citroën","Cadillac","Bugatti","Bentley","Alfa Romeo","Dodge"]
    return gimmeOne(makes)
}

class Car:NSObject {
    var make: String

    override init() {
        self.make = gimmeCarMake()
    }
}

//create list of cars
var carList = [Car]()
for _ in 0..<10 {
    carList.append(Car())
}
carList


//sort list
carList.sort { $0.make < $1.make }
carList


func firstLetter(text: String) -> String {
    let position = 0
    let index = advance(text.startIndex, position)
    let character = "\(text[index])"
    return character
}


//goal - to be used in tableView index section
//["A"] = ["Acura","Aston Martin","Audi"]
//["B"] = ["BMW","Bentley"]
//["C"] = ["Cadillac","Citroën"]
//["D"] = ["Dodge"]
```

**Edit:**
Let's see if I can lose the rest of my reputation points.

I came back with the final answer in code, and it's generic enough so that anyone can use it with just a few quick changes.  If you need steps to follow, check out [this page](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing/).

Hope it helps someone.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  tmpSortTable
//
// Solution from:
// http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/04/uitableview-sectioning-and-indexing/
//

import UIKit

class MyObject:NSObject {
    var thingA: String
    var thingB: String
    var section: Int?  //make room in your object for this

    class func gimmeOne(things: [String]) -> String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random()) % things.count
        let choice = things[randomNumber]
        return choice
    }

    class func gimmeCarMake() -> String {
        let makes = ["Ford","Audi","Hennessey","Acura","Infiniti","BMW","Lexus","Jeep","Subaru","Nissan","Aston Martin","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Toyota","Volkswagen","Scion","Mitsubishi","Mini","Lotus","Lamborghini","Jaguar","Hyundai","Citroën","Cadillac","Bugatti","Bentley","Alfa Romeo","Dodge","Tesla"]
        return gimmeOne(makes)
    }

    class func gimmeCarModel() -> String {
        let model = ["F150","Mustang","LFA","S55","Raptor","Odyssey","NSX","4C","F40","F50","F70","LaFerrari","Camry","Silverado","Viper","Routan","Quattro","M100","P85 D","Stealth","Pinto","Accord"]
        return gimmeOne(model)
    }

    override init() {
        self.thingA = MyObject.gimmeCarMake()
        self.thingB = MyObject.gimmeCarModel()
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "\n\(thingA) \(thingB) in section \(section)"
    }
}



class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    //setup
    var data = [MyObject]()  //main list of data to be used

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createData()
    }

    //create data or fill data any way you want
    func createData() {
        for _ in 0..<50 {
            data.append(MyObject())
        }
    }

    //now the important section stuff
    class Section {
        var items: [MyObject] = []

        func addItem(item: MyObject) {
            self.items.append(item)
        }

    }

    // `UIKit` convenience class for sectioning a table
    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
    var sections: [Section] {
        if self._sections != nil {
            return self._sections!
        }

        //identify item to section
        var items: [MyObject] = data.map { dataItem in
            dataItem.section = self.collation.sectionForObject(dataItem, collationStringSelector: "thingA")
            return dataItem
        }

        //create empty sections
        var sections = [Section]()
        for _ in 0..<self.collation.sectionIndexTitles.count {
            sections.append(Section())
        }

        //put each item into a section
        for item in items {
            sections[item.section!].addItem(item)
        }

        //sort each section
        for section in sections {
            section.items = self.collation.sortedArrayFromArray(section.items, collationStringSelector: "thingA") as [MyObject]
        }

        self._sections = sections
        return self._sections!
    }
    var _sections: [Section]?





    //TableView data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sections[section].items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = self.sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = "\(item.thingA) \(item.thingB)"
        return cell
    }

    /* section headers appear above each `UITableView` section */
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
        // do not display empty `Section`s
        if !self.sections[section].items.isEmpty {
            return self.collation.sectionTitles[section] as String
        }
        return ""
    }

    /* section index titles displayed to the right of the `UITableView` */
    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject] {
        return self.collation.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return self.collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this tutorial [Indexed Table View in Swift](http://www.edumobile.org/ios/indexed-table-views-in-swift/) in Swift. You'll want to make use of the UILocalizedIndexedCollation convenience class for creating the index instead of doing it manually or programatically. It uses the locales defined in your Project Localizations list. This way you won't have to create the list yourself, or by writing code to do it, and requires less maintenance moving forward as you add / remove more entries. This will also be able to take advantage of any localization you end up doing in your application.

You can also check out [UILocalized​Indexed​Collation on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/) for more details on using the class.

Comment: Brocken URL. Please check.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan The tutorial I linked to is now gone. I added a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the code below and execute the buildIndex(words) to get something like this:

[(A, [Acura, Auston Martin, Audi]),
 (B, [BMW, Bentley]),
 (C, [Cadilac, Citroen]),
....
]

```
import Foundation

let makes = ["Ford","Audi","Hennessey","Acura","Infiniti","BMW","Lexus","Jeep","Subaru","Nissan","Aston Martin","Mercedes-Benz","Porsche","Toyota","Volkswagen","Scion","Mitsubishi","Mini","Lotus","Lamborghini","Jaguar","Hyundai","Citroën","Cadillac","Bugatti","Bentley","Alfa Romeo","Dodge"]

let words = makes.sorted({$0 < $1})

typealias Entry = (Character, [String])

func distinct<T: Equatable>(source: [T]) -> [T] {
  var unique = [T]()
  for item in source {
    if !contains(unique, item) {
      unique.append(item)
    }
  }
  return unique
}

func buildIndex(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
  let letters = words.map {
    (word) -> Character in
    Character(word.substringToIndex(advance(word.startIndex, 1)
      ).uppercaseString)
  }
  let distinctLetters = distinct(letters)

  return distinctLetters.map {
    (letter) -> Entry in
    return (letter, words.filter {
      (word) -> Bool in
     Character(word.substringToIndex(advance(word.startIndex, 1)
       ).uppercaseString) == letter
    })
  }
}
```